# Converting MongoDB $max result to golang data

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I try to get max values from MongoDB collection from my Go code. 
What type should I use to decode result?

When I use `bson.D{}` as `val2` type the result looks like `[{_id <nil>} {max 66} {cnt 14}]`.

Here's the code:

```
    filter := []bson.M{{
        "$group": bson.M{
            "_id": nil,
            "max": bson.M{"$max": "$hellid"},
        }},
    }

    cursor, err := collection.Aggregate(ctx, filter)

    for cursor.Next(ctx) {
        val2 := ???
        err := cursor.Decode(&val2)
        fmt.Printf("cursor: %v, value: %v\n", cursor.Current, val2)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `bson.D` already works as you presented. The problem may be you can't "easily" get out the `max` and `cnt` values.

Model your result document with a struct like this:

```
type result struct {
    Max   int `bson:"max"`
    Count int `bson:"cnt"
}
```

Although `cnt` is not produced by the example code you provided.

And then:

```
var res result
err := cursor.Decode(&res)
```

Comment: I simply didn't need `_id`. Great thanks (despite it's forbidden:) )